# How is Java Graphics' fillRect(int, int, int, int) implemented [Low level graphics programming]?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to write a fill rectangle function for my project. And I was wondering how the `fillRect(int, int, int, int)` method of Java's `java.awt.Graphics` class is implemented. I tried finding the source code by right clicking in a Java program and "Open Declaration" (in the eclipse IDE) but all I can find is the abstract declaration of the method.

Basically I want to know how a simple Java code like this:

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 620, 460);
    }
```

can produce a green rectangle like the on in the window below:

[image: Green rectangle in a window]

I only know of two shape filling methods : the Flood-fill & Boundary-fill algorithms .
The issue with those is that they both needs existing boundaries (monochrome for Boundary-fill and mono- or polychrome for Flood-fill).

so that with the boundary-fill algorithm it would be something like :

```
void fillRect(int x, int y, int w, int h){
    drawLine(x, y, x+w, y);     // Draw top boundary
    drawLine(x, y+h, x+w, y+h); // Draw bottom boundary
    drawLine(x, y, x, y+h);     // Draw left boundary
    drawLine(x+w, y, x+w, y+h); // Draw right boundary
    boundaryFill4D(x+1, y+1, GREEN, GREEN); // for simplicity I'm hardcoding color
}

void boundaryFill4D(int x, int y, int fill_color, int boundary_color)
{
    if(getpixel(x, y) != boundary_color &&
       getpixel(x, y) != fill_color)
    {
        putpixel(x, y, fill_color);
        boundaryFill4D(x + 1, y, fill_color, boundary_color);
        boundaryFill4D(x, y + 1, fill_color, boundary_color);
        boundaryFill4D(x - 1, y, fill_color, boundary_color);
        boundaryFill4D(x, y - 1, fill_color, boundary_color);
    }
}
```

As you can see from this example I had to first draw the 4 sides before I could "bucket fill" the the outlined rectangle. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: My guess is that it's operating system dependent.  Here's the Windows [Graphics.FillRectangle Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillrectangle?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc the examples shown doesn't show what algorithm/set of instruction, fill rectangle is made of. it is just documenting the use of the method.

Comment: My guess is that video memory is modified directly using whatever formula is the fastest.